# config modeline

Tags: mode-line-format

I define a variable like this

```
(if (w32-get-ime-open-status)
  (setq ime-state “zh-cn”)
  (setq ime-state “en-us”))
```

I want ime-state to be used to the modeline.  In order for the variable value to be up-to-date I need the function `w32-get-ime-open-status` to be called accordingly.  How can I ensure that?

mode-line package: powerline

Comment: What do you mean by "it"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 'it' == ime-state ,

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```el
(add-to-list 'mode-line-misc-info '(" " ime-state))
```

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `mode-line-format` will show you where in your format value the `mode-line-misc-info` value appears, and the documentation explains the format.  For this change, we're combining these:

- "A list whose car is a string or list is processed by processing each of the list elements recursively, as separate mode line constructs, and concatenating the results."
- "For any symbol other than t or nil, the symbol’s value is processed as a mode line construct.  As a special exception, if that value is a string, the string is processed verbatim, without handling any %-constructs."

Hence prefixing a space to the string value of your variable.

For full details, refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Mode Line Format`

Comment: it doesn't worked,

Comment: `mode-line-misc-info` is part of the default mode line, and I've tested my suggestion.  I suggest that you repeat the test, starting from `emacs -Q` -- it should work.  Then you'll have to figure out what's different in your normal config.

Comment: ok,it is my fault,I use powerline as modeline ,

Comment: if I use bare modeline , when I update this variable ,could modeline update the same time , otherwize ,could you give me you test elisp code ,thanks

Comment: The mode line usually gets refreshed very frequently, however you can force that if necessary, after setting your variable.  See `C-h f force-mode-line-update`.

Comment: I don't know much about powerline, so you should look at its documentation to find out how best to add things to it.

Comment: That said, I would expect that ultimately it's setting `mode-line-format` and therefore, failing any more useful documentation, you could still start from that point in order to figure out where to add things.